# Targeting action bar menu items with ShowCaseView

Tags: android, showcaseview

How can I target the action bar menu items with [ShowCaseView.](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

I have tried using the following code located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20296637) and I am getting `ITEM_ACTION_ITEM cannot be resolved or is not a field`

How can I target specific ActionBar menu items using ShowCaseView? thanks

```
        ShowcaseView sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseViewWithType(ShowcaseView.ITEM_ACTION_ITEM,
            R.id.answers, FragmentViewNovice.this,"Edit", 
           "Click here to edit image.");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future Googlers, I have found the answer.

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTarget(new ActionItemTarget(getActivity(), R.id.answers)) //Here is where you supply the id of the action bar item you want to display
    .setContentTitle("Title")
    .setContentText("Description")
    .hideOnTouchOutside()
    .build();
```

Comment: Are there Any Other Alternatives ? Because It didn't work for me

Comment: @Prabhakar Sorry, this was the only solution I found and it worked for me.